# CakePHP displaying file list of /app/webroot instead of homepage view

Tags: apache, cakephp

My CakePHP(ver 1.2) application works fine in following configuration
Apache version  2.2.17
PHP version     5.2.17
MySQL version   5.0.92-community-log
cPanel Version  11.30.6 (build 3)

But displays file list of /app/webroot instead of homepage view in following configuration
Apache version  1.3.42
PHP version 5.2.14
MySQL version   5.0.92-community
cPanel Version  11.30.6 (build 3)

It sometimes displayed message like server does not know how to handle that file or something like that. Is it because of different apache version? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the `index.php` file is inside this directory app/webroot?

Comment: index.php is alright. It works great in our test server and our production server which both are configured as first one. Second configuration is our client's one.

Comment: Is a shared or dedicated hosting? This happens when folder doesn't have a index.php file or your httpd configuration doesn't have index.php in variable DirectoryIndex. You can also try to have simply a file index.php with `phpinfo()`.

Comment: It also happens on a misconfigured mod_rewrite on apache

Answer (score 0):

I guess petervaz was right. It happened due to a mis-configured mod_rewrite.